# Javascript sdk facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I got to do a facebook API for a university project. I'm trying to get these values from Facebook.

> current user name and id.
>   friends geo-location, friends id and names, mutual friends.

I have never in my life seen the Javascript SDK so I try to work over a few examples in the web.

I got this:

```
    //facebook app id
var mis_amigos_id = new Array();
var mis_amigos_name = new Array();
appid='512456102098788';
channelurl='www.astrophilia.com.ar/facebook-load-friends/includes/channel.html';

//function to get current userid
function getUser()
{
    FB.init({
        appId      : '512456102098788', // App ID
        channelUrl : 'www.astrophilia.com.ar/facebook-load-friends/includes/channel.html', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    //check current user login status
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            loadFriends();
        } else {
            //user is not connected.
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    loadFriends();
                } else {
                    alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

//funcion que carga amigos, this function load the friends
function loadFriends()
{
    //i think this is a json objet with all the data
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var divContainer=$('.facebook-friends');
        //this for sees all friends
        for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++)
            {
                mis_amigos_id[i] = response.data[i].id;
                mis_amigos_name[i] = response.data[i].name;
                document.write(mis_amigos_name[i]+" tiene el id "+mis_amigos_id[i]+"</ br>");

                // original code: creates a img element: response.data.id is the id of the current friend
                                                                                                                                                                                 //$(document.createElement("img")).attr({ src: 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+response.data[i].id+'/picture', title: response.data[i].name ,onClick:'alert("You poked "+this.title);'})
                                                                                                                                                                                 //apend to div container. osea que imprime la imagen en el div.
               // .appendTo(divContainer);       
            }
    });
}

//start from here
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.load-button').click(function(){
        getUser();
    });
});
```

There is a problem with the document.write.
And I'm not sure if the two arrays that save the id and name are working.
I've got no idea how to get mutual friends and geo-location

Here is the online version: [www.astrophilia.com.ar](http://www.astrophilia.com.ar)

Comment: i would start by using the correct code for the implementation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ - see "Loading and Initialization"

Comment: i cant get it work whit the facebook original implementation